# How do I get the old blue sms alert box for notification of new text messages?

Tags: ios

I used to get SMS alerts in lock screen which showed a blue box with the option of "close" or "reply". Now I get a green slider box with a white bubble. How can I change this back? I have set the notification to "alert" .

Comment: Were you jailbroken? It sounds like a jailbreak tweak, since I believe it never worked like that.

Comment: What's interesting is that standard iOS never displayed a blue box like the one you described on the lock screen. _However,_ it can be configured to display a box just like you described when the phone is unlocked and one receives a message. If you were to receive a message with your phone unlocked right now, it should display the blue box you described. Test it and let us know what you find.

Comment: No.the blue box comes up in non lock screen mode. Can it be changed to come up in locked screen mode? Thanks bassplayer. That seems to be spot on. Can it be changed to get the blue box in lock mode?

Comment: I suppose it's hard to make a picture of something that is changed, but can you find an internet picture showing what you seek and link to that?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're describing the style of text-message notifications pre- and post-iOS 5 (when Notification Center was introduced).

If I'm not mistaken, the first case looks something like this:

[image: pre-iOS 5 lock-screen notification]

And the current case looks like this:

[image: post-iOS 5 lock-screen notification]

Unfortunately, there's no built-in way to revert this change: while the style of the iOS modal popup that appears to inform you of an alert while you're *using* the phone still looks the same (bluish background with acknowledgement buttons), the style of lock-screen notifications (whether the phone is *locked* or not) have changed to a black background with an app-specific icon that can be swiped to activate the alerting app.

Short of some sort of Jailbreak tweak, or somehow downgrading your iOS version, there's no way to undo this change.